# Ubuntu 20.04 very slow after update

Tags: 20.04, updates

after doing the
sudo apt update;sudo apt dist-upgrade -y;sudo apt autoremove -y;sudo apt autoclean -y
as usually my notebook is very slow (didn't happen on any other machine so far)

see this from 7z b -mmt1

Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-1035G1 CPU @ 1.00GHz (706E5)
CPU Freq: 64000000 64000000 64000000 - - - 512000000 1024000000 1024000000

```
RAM size:    7718 MB,  # CPU hardware threads:   8
RAM usage:    435 MB,  # Benchmark threads:      1

                   Compressing  |                  Decompressing
Dict     Speed Usage    R/U Rating  |      Speed Usage    R/U Rating
     KiB/s     %   MIPS   MIPS  |      KiB/s     %   MIPS   MIPS

22:        299    99    293    292  |       2112    99    182    180
23:        249   100    256    255  |       2279   100    198    197
24:        286    99    312    308  |       2218   100    196    195
25:        277    99    319    317  |       2277   100    204    203
----------------------------------  | ------------------------------
Avr:              99    295    293  |               99    195    194
Tot:              99    245    243
```

it was much faster in the passt. Also It' a 3.6GHZ  machine.

I tried also to reinstall but even the bootstick was so slow that I can't use it.

did anyone notice such a habit ? or has a hint on what could cause that ?

Comment: Check /var/log/syslog for error messages. Run `top` to see what the biggest resource users are. Run `free` to see if you are swapping or out of memory. Since it's a laptop, check your temperatures, fan function, and airflow (CPUs throttle down to prevent overheating).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I checked and it looks ok. Also the slowness can be seen when booting the intsall image.

Comment: Please put additional information in your Question above, not in comments. Comments are intended to help you improve your question so it is answerable. Comments are not intended for conversation. At the moment, you haven't given us much information on what's slow or why beyond 7z. "It looks ok" is vague: it doesn't tell us what you checked, or what you though OK looks like. We are not there; we cannot see it. Our only data is the specifics you provide. Booting the install image has discrete steps -- when is it slow? Compared to what?

Comment: @user535733 thanks for your replies. I have already mentioned the usb stick boot in the questeion. Also the i5-1035G1 CPU @ 1.00GHz leads to some odd problem as there is no such a prozessor. Your first guess might be right that a strange power saving issue is preventing a faster usage but nothing to see with any tool